# How to return the value of a grid located inside a popup window calling javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a popup window containing a grid. I have called this popup window in my javascript like this:

```
popupWindow = window.open('gridjsp1.jsp', "_blank", "directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no,width=600, height=280,top=200,left=250");
if(popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed)
    popupWindow.focus();
```

`gridjsp1.jsp` contains the code for the grid. This returns a value on grid click. I need this value to be returned to the calling javascript function, ie. where the popup is written. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.opener` in the popup window to get the reference object of the parent window. More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.opener).

Something like this should work:

Parent window:

```
function setGridValue (gridValue) {
    alert(gridValue);
}
```

From the popup window call like this:

```
window.opener.setGridValue("YOUR_NEW_VALUE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read about [window.parent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp)?